# CTRL+F Find/Search not active after clean install of Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: shortcuts, search, find

2 days after a completely clean install of 13.04 and no relevant changes to the system (keybd shortcuts etc.), CTRL+F does not work anywhere, with the exception of Chrome, where it opens the "Settings" window

Other apps like Firefox, Thunderbird and Libre Office have the element CTRL+F grayed out.

(PS for info -  I am running English language Ubuntu 13.04  with a German keyboard,  but never had any problems in the past with this combination)

Any ideas??

Comment: CTRL+F is working for me on 13.04 at least in Libre Office and Firefox.

Comment: Try checking your keyword layout in ``gnome-control-center``

Comment: NONE of the shortcuts listed in Keyboard Shortcuts work

Comment: and CTRL-F not listed anyway

Answer (score 4):

Goto System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers. Now select 'Search' and hit the 'Backspace' button on the keyboard. Make sure the shortcut is now 'Disabled'. Now 'Ctrl+F' will work as usual.

Comment: Don't know why this is not the default in 2017...

Answer (score 1):

If you have xbindkeys, and created a sample `~/.xbindkeysrc` file,
this sample file includes a binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *middle mouse button*.

Open this file (in your home folder, hidden); search for xterm and comment those  lines by adding a '`#`' at the beginning:

```
# set directly keycode (here Ctrl + F with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  c:41 + m:0x4

# specify a mouse button
#"xterm"
# control + b:2
```

You do not need to delete any other custom entries.
(Unless you bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to something, or something to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> )

P.S. I suggested commenting control + b:2 because it can cause problems also, but it is not related to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and commenting that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer!  I was having the same problem and this is what I did to fix it. Open up terminal and type: "xbindkeys-config" (without the quotes).  That will open up a window, delete the entries out of the there and then hit "Save & Apply & Exit" on the right hand side and Ctrl + F will now find again.